# Resize into square the single product image in woocommerce without cropping

Tags: images, woocommerce-offtopic

Hi everyone badly need your help about my image on a single product page in woocommerce i have my image size 1400x800px and uploaded it with out checking the hard crop settings in woocommerce. I would like to align it vertically center on its container how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your image to be exact square, you must turn on the "hard crop" in settings.

If you want to choose the cropping area for each image manually - there is a good plugin Manual Image Crop.